# Tempo para dar update - JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

Fala ae galera blz?

Existe alguma maneira nativa de eu dar um update em algum componente após alguns segundos?

Consegui fazer de forma nativa usando o "p:remoteCommand"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

você pode usar o p:pool do primefaces.

```
<p:poll interval="60" listener="#{meuBean.funcao}"
            update="idDaTabelaFormEtc" />
```

o interval define os segundos.

Comment: Massa cara, funcionou tbm :D

Comment: haha, eu ja respondi esta mesma dúvida umas 3 vezes por aqui :P
o showcase do primefaces não é muito efetivo. Abraço!

Comment: pô cara pior que é verdade.. valeu mesmo. Abraço tbm mano